# Initializing value of a cell in one WorkBook to another WorkBook using Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. Was trying to write a global macro for a scenario. The scenario is,

1. I have WorkBook1 (WB1) which will be my global Macro work book.
2. I have actual WorkBook(WB2) where I have all data being calculated.

Now I want to write a macro which can actually initialize a value of a cell in WB2 in to a cell in WB1. The equation will look like something like,

```
WB1.sheet1.cell(2,1) = WB2.sheet7.cells(2,2) '--> (Sheet7 is a sheet in WB2)
```

I am actually initializing the values of WB2(B2) cell to WB1(A1) cell.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What code do you have so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: where do you `Set` the `WB1` and `WB2` workbook objects ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full example, in which I assume that `wb1` contains the macro and `wb2` will be opened on the spot:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("SomePath\Somefile.xlsx")

    'Set cell B2 on sheet7 in the data calculation workbook (somefile.xlsx) to be equal to the Macro workbook sheet 1 range A1.
    wb2.Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B2").Value = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    'Or the other way around: Get a value from the calc wb into the macro wb: 
    wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B2").Value
End Sub
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment - Sure you can take the workbook path from somewhere, however you need to open the workbook in order to work with the objects (sheets, cells, etc.) inside of it.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim path as string
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    path = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").value 'Put "Somepath\Somefile.xlsx" without the quotes in this range.
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(path)

    'Set cell B2 on sheet7 in the data calculation workbook (somefile.xlsx) to be equal to the Macro workbook sheet 1 range A1.
    wb2.Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B2").Value = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    'Or the other way around: Get a value from the calc wb into the macro wb: 
    wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B2").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code. Can we add an actual path to the variable "wb2"?
Some thing like this, 

Set wb2 = "SomePath\Somefile.xlsx"

Comment: You keep putting a value from wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1") column A into the second workbook in B2 on sheet 7 until you hit an empty value in the "macro workbook". Define "not working", since you are actually writing into the B2 cell.

Comment: So, the macro gives an error "Subscript out of range" (Error 9).

Sub Example()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("path\sample.xlsx")

i = 2

Do While Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

wb2.Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B2").Value = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)

i = i + 1
Loop
wb2.Save
wb2.Close
End Sub

Comment: Could be referencing a .Cells(i, 1) where i is bigger than the max row, or you do not have a sheet named "Sheet7" in Wb2 or you do not have a worksheet named "Sheet1" in Wb1, or replace "path\sample.xlsx" to an actual Wb. I assume you can adapt this code by doing some of your own research and use F8 to step through the code to find the troubling line. I do not have the time to troubleshoot your adaptation step by step - The answer to your question (get cell value from 1 wb to the other) is already provided above. Sorry, but either  start a new question or troubleshoot yourself.

Comment: Hey Rik, Thanks for the troubleshooting part. My code works now. So, the error was, There's no Sheet with that name in actual WorkBook.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you calculate everything first on workbook2, then copy paste all the values from workbook2 to workbook1, easy is it not?.